# How to divide a singlepart polygon shapefile of urban streets into a multipart polygon in order to get several streets?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, multipart, streets

I am working in QGIS and I have this road shapefile (singlepart polygon). How to split this polygon into a multipart polygon by splitting geometry at that point when the orientation changes? In order to have several street geometries.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the `advanced digitizing toolbar`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't do this manually by using the advanced digitizing toolbar because the study area has a very big extension. My goal is to follow a procedure by using some gis tools.

Comment: What have you tried then?

Comment: I've tried to divide the vector geometry by using the "subdivide" option, but It doesn't work well. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use GRASS GIS, then the `v.clean` module splits all linestrings at all intersections. You would call the command with the option:

```
v.clean input=<your road vector> output=roads_clean tool=break,rmdupl thresh=0,0
```

You will, of course, have to import the roads layer into GRASS first.

Answer (score 0):

Ah wait, these are polygons?? Then my suggestion won't work. :-(
I think you'll have to shrink the polygons down to centerlines, then split the centerlines layer.
(BTW: "single part" refers to a layer that's split up. "Multipart" indicates a layer with a single polygon made up of many individual segments)